# ¿Como puedo generar una imagen de mi sitio usando jspdf y html2canvas?

Tags: javascript

he tratado de realizarlo utilizando este código pero no me funciona

```
    function genPDF() {

        html2canvas(document.body, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {

                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                var doc = new jsPDF();

                doc.save('document.pdf');

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Buenos días Jos, echale un vistazo a [ask] para mejorar las preguntas y obtener mas ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solo te falto agregar la imagen al documento:

```
function genPDF() {
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0); //agregar la imagen al documento
            doc.save('document.pdf');
        }
    });
}
```